# Add another Website to my Page on load using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add another wesbite on my webpage.

```
<script>
$("#new-nav").load("https://google.com");
</script>
```

This is exactly what I would like to achieve. I would like to load another page using an url on my current page

```
 <script>
    $("#new-nav").load("http://localhost:8080/xyz/page");
    </script>
```

but it's not working..

```
<div id="new-nav"></div>
```

How do I achieve this? I would like a jQuery solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Check in `browser` that this url `http://localhost:8080/xyz/page` is running individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on load add another website

your secure browser won't accept in that way.
you are doing a wrong thing and [**violating the origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

use something like

```
$('#new-nav').html('<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/xyz/page"></iframe>');
```

If it is your same site

check localhost:8080/xyz/page is working or not and wrap your code in document.ready function.other wise your script wont fire.

Comment: the current page is from my website only so i want this page on another page section

Comment: @SachinRawal  see my updated answer.let me nknow if you still face any problem.

Comment: perfect...thats what i wanted to do..actully want to avoid iframe but yes as i can see there no other option i guess

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue may be due to the `.load` request being an AJAX request. If it is in a different domain, it will not load correctly.

[More Info on jQuery .load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<iframe id='otherSite'></iframe>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#otherSite').load('http://localhost:8080/xyz/page');
    });
</script>
```